# Accurately timing how long a function takes to run

Tags: java, queue

I'm trying to record the time taken to enqueue and dequeue a specific number of Strings to a linked list queue.

If I set the number of strings manually, every time the program is run comes back with more or less the same elapsed time.

However if I ask the user for input (as below), and enter the same number the program takes twice as long to run most times. I don't understand how this is happening since I don't start the timer until just before the queueing and dequeuing function is called.

```
public static void main(String[], args){
    long start, elapsed;
    int num = Integer.parseInt(javax.swing.JOptionPane.showInputDialog("State the number of elements to queue:"));
    System.out.println("Processing " + num + " strings..."); 

    Queue lq = new LinkedQueue();

    // timing section
    start = System.nanoTime();    
    testQueue(num, lq);
    elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - start;
}
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: `enqueue and dequeue a specific number of Strings`---How are the strings generated ? Randomly or hard-coded.

Comment: It uses a for loop in the function to generate "String1", "String2", etc, up to num

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expecting deterministic behaviour and i guess you are running that program on a PC with a normal OS. So its not possible to expect exact timing mainly because:

1. you are running a VM for java code to execute in
2. the VM runs in an OS.

The VM does things you dont control and the OS aswel. So you can only make a rough guess on how much time your program is going to take to execute unless you run your program in an adequate environment.

The garbage collector could be interrupting your program in the middle of its execution or the scheduler could schedule you out for another more important process, etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information it is difficult to say. It could well be that waiting for user input is somehow discouraging the JIT compiler from compiling the function and it ends up being interpreted instead and taking a longer time.